# Shared Preferences storage

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

So I am creating a simple android application for education purpose. I have a menu item which has 3 check boxes in it. As soon as my app starts, the user can select one or more from the given check boxes.but, I want to save the user selection for further reference. I achieved this for 1 of the check boxes using shared preferences but I am unable to achieve this if more than 1 check boxes are selected. Here is my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static Switch swch;
    static TextView onOffBar;
    public static boolean red = false;
    public static boolean blue = false;
    public static boolean green = false;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
 }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        boolean isChecked = settings.getBoolean("checkbox", false);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.red);
//        MenuItem item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.blue);
//        MenuItem item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.green);
        item.setChecked(isChecked);
//        item1.setChecked(isChecked);
//        item2.setChecked(isChecked);
        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.red:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                editor.putBoolean("checkbox", item.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.blue:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                editor.putBoolean("checkbox", item.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.green:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                editor.putBoolean("checkbox", item.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

How do I achieve this for all the switch case options using shared preferences?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is wasn't your meant I apologize. But basically you are on the right track and you just need to enter in a different key for each boolean you want saved and to check. Also, its best practice to use a more descriptive key for the preferences, so instead of using something like "checkbox" that could apply to anything try using a descriptor so you can better keep track and remember what its for in the long run.

```
     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.red:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                editor.putBoolean("red", item.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
                return true;
                Case R.id.blue:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                Blue1 = item.isChecked();
                editor.putBoolean("blue", Blue1);
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.green:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                Green1=item.isChecked();
                editor.putBoolean("green", Green1);
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Devsil..I tried this but when the app is getting killed, the state of the checkboxes is not getting saved. What changes should I make?

Comment: Not entirely sure what that is the case, maybe try replacing the commit() in the editor with apply()

Answer (score -2):

You can use Gson to store a Model Object.

```
public class CheckboxData {
    boolean personalize_permissions;
    boolean add_tanslucent_layer;
    boolean integrate_flowInfo;
}
```

Add following in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Create an object of CheckboxData and populate it according to your checkbox selections.

```
CheckboxData data = new CheckBoxData();
data.setPersonalize_permissions(true);
data.setIntegrate_flowInfo(true);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(data);
prefsEditor.putString("CheckBoxPrefs", json);
```

When retrieving

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("CheckBoxPrefs", "");
CheckboxData prefData = gson.fromJson(json, CheckboxData.class);
```

Set the selected checkboxes as per `prefData` values.

Comment: Though this is technically correct it may be entirely overkill for what he/she is attempting to do.